# How should I represent a huffman tree to be used in a Color Computer program?

Tags: assembly, tree, compression, huffman-code

I created a silly Huffman compressor in Python, so I can compress image/sound data to be applied in my Tandy Color Computer Projects. The decompressor is written in 6809 Assembly. 
I couldn't find a way to store the huffman tree, so I generated Assembly code that walks into the tree and get the correct uncompressed data. Here is an example:

```
DECOMP_HUFFMAN:        PSHS    A,B,X,Y,U
                       LDB     #8
                       STB     $2100
                       pshs    x
                       ldx     $2102
                       stx     $2106
                       puls    x                       
                       LDB     ,X+
                       JMP     inicio
prox_bit:              LSLB
                       PSHS    CC
                       DEC     $2100
                       BNE     S_P_B
                       LDB     #8
                       STB     $2100
                       LDB       ,X+
S_P_B:                 PULS    CC
                       RTS
armazena:              STA       ,U+
                       LEAY    -1,Y
                       BNE      inicio
                       PULS   U,Y,X,B,A
                       RTS


inicio:     jsr prox_bit
            tfr  cc,a
            anda #1
            sta  $2104
            lda ($2102)
            bne  n1
            lda $2104
n0:         pshs x
            ldx  $2102
            leax 1,x
            lda  a,x            
            puls x
            bsr  armazena
            pshs x
            ldx  $2106
            stx  $2102
            puls x
            bra inicio


n1:         cmpa #1
            bne  n2
            lda  $2104
            bne  n0
            bra  n4

n2:         cmpa #2
            bne  n3
            lda  $2104
            beq  n0

n3:         lda  $2104
n4:         pshs x
            ldx   $2102
            leax  1,x
            lda   a,x
            leax  a,x            
            stx   $2102
            puls x
            bra   inicio
```

I would like to use the real huffman tree, instead of creating the Assembly code to do it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just for curiosity - how did you generate the assembly code?

Comment: The python code that compresses the data generate the assembly code based on the real Huffman tree. As a matter of fact, the assembly generated code is a crude tree traverser that uses the bits from de compressed data to traverse the tree and fetch the uncompressed data. The Huffman tree branches become the branches of the assembly program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transmit a Huffman code simply by sending the code length for each symbol.  You do not need to send a tree.  A code length of zero indicates that that symbol does not occur.

What you send might be something like:

```
A: 2
B: 0
C: 0
D: 3
E: 1
F: 0
G: 0
H: 0
I: 3
J: 0
```

Where you only send the numbers -- the assignment to symbols is in symbol order.

Both ends would assume a canonical Huffman code, where the code values are assigned in order from the shortest code lengths to the longest.  Within a bit length, the codes are assigned incrementally to the symbols in their order.  For example (symbol: code length - code):

```
E: 1 - 0
A: 2 - 10
D: 3 - 110
I: 3 - 111
```

Now the decoder only has to compare the low bits with integer values at the cutoff between each bit length (store the bits above reversed), starting with the shortest.  Within each bit length, an index from the start provides an offset into a lookup table for the symbol.

Comment: I'll try that and then I'll tell you if it works, Maybe I need checking my python compressor so it generates a canonical huffman tree after all. Thanks a lot!

The code for the compressor is located at https://github.com/robsonfr/random-source-codes/blob/master/poltergeist-utils/compression.py

Comment: You can find an example of such a decoder in puff.c at https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/develop/contrib/puff .